# XSL plain text indents when including another xsl file

Tags: xslt

I have a plain text XSL template which works fine and does not indent.

I then added another XSL template to this template with the following line:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl')"></xsl:copy-of>
```

When the XSL is rendered, the text within the AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl file is indented.

How can I prevent this?

My full XSL is:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
<xsl:template match="/Email">
<xsl:text>To Our Valued Customer:</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Welcome, and thank you .....blah blah blah</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>Sincerely,</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>My Company</xsl:text>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl')"></xsl:copy-of>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl is:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:text>About This Message</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>You received this email because you subscribed to our electronic notification service. If you no longer wish to receive electronic notifications, etc...</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Expected Output result is:

> To Our Valued Customer:
>
> Welcome, and thank you .....blah blah blah
>
> Sincerely,
>
> My Company      About This Message You received this email because you
>   subscribed to our electronic notification service. If you no longer
>   wish to receive electronic notifications, etc...
>
> However, About This Message, and You received... are indented.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: Please show us a sample of AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl, then explain how the output of that file should look in your plain text result.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by changing the AboutThisMessagePlainText.xsl to a text file. This prevented the text from being indented.

The text file looks like:

```
<text>



About This Message

You received this email because you subscribed to our electronic notification service. If you no longer wish to receive electronic notifications, etc...
</text>
```